# Why do the table column change size, and how can I stop it

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a content editable div on each row that has a colspan when you type in the content area, the 1st column shrinks in size changing the size of the div. eventually it word wraps. I don't want the layout of the table to change (horizontally). How can I prevent this?

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>id</th><th>Comments</th><th>Other stuff</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td colspan="2"><div contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 1em; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td colspan="2"><div contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 1em; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"></div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This one without the first column doesn't do it.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Comments</th><th>Other stuff</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><div contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 1em; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><div contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 1em; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"></div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if it is about table-layout : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout ... but 3 col with 2 already equal to 100% gives extra width to start with . remove it and set only a width to the col supposed not to resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i am using uses points from @G-Cyr and @Amanullah Tanweer

HTML

```
<table class="has-comments">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>id</th><th>Comments</th><th>Other stuff</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td colspan="2"><div contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 1em; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td colspan="2"><div contenteditable="true" style="min-height: 1em; width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;"></div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table.has-comments {
    width: 100%;
}
```

javascript

```
$("table.has-comments tr:first-child th").each(function(index){
    let element = $(this);
    let width = element.width();
    element.css("width", width + "px");
});
$("table.has-comments").css("table-layout", "fixed");
```

The result is, I let the page set up the table (width 100%), then javascript/jQuery fixes column widths. Lastly the table-layout is set to fixed. It's not the most efficient solution, I know, but my page is rendered dynamically by jsp and can vary from day to day.

Answer (score 3):

Table columns always change width dynamically due to their content if their `width` is not defined. In your case, the `width` is only defined for the `div` *inside*  the `td` (and with a relative value: 100%, which simply fills the `td`, and which also causes the td to expand if there's more content since the `td` itself doesn't have any `width` setting), which doesn't affect the `td`, hence the width change according to content.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding width to table headers like this

```
<th style="width: 100px">
```

So the width of column will not change when content size increase of decrease.